# Webclient.DownloadDataAsync Download and use bytes at the same time

Tags: c#, wpf, webclient

I'm working on a music player, it finds from web, downloads the bytes async, plays it, and when the program closes, it deletes all downloaded musics. So, it downloads temporarily.

I want to play the music while it was downloading. i guess it can be done from

```
    private static void Downloader_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

this but this `e` only shows the percentage, not downloaded bytes. It's something like loading a video from youtube, you can watch it even not fully loaded. I trying to make it happen with musics.

Comment: You can not do this using the `WebClient`. You have to build your own streamed downloader using a [**`HttpWebRequest`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest(v=vs.95).aspx).

Comment: [**This**](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b489fe1d-a237-48ac-b58a-f901e1b03bde/file-download-how-to-use-httpwebrequestrespone?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs) can be helpful.

Comment: You can also try to use the HttpClient class instead of WebClient